# Area 51 discussion site shows as "unknown site discussion" in Android app

Tags: feature-request, bug, android-app

I noticed that a question on the Area 51 discussion site shows up as "Unknown Site" in the Android app:

[image]

This should say "Area 51 Discussion Zone".

Comment: Edited with smaller screenshot. Click for bigger image. See [here](http://meta.anime.stackexchange.com/questions/593/how-can-i-streamline-images-and-screenshots-i-embed-into-my-post) for more details about streamlining images and screenshots.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha I uploaded this directly from my mobile device by taking a screenshot, so I sort of depend on others to resize the image for me...