# Area 51 site shown as unknown sites

Tags: bug, android-app

Don't close this question as a duplicate of either [Area 51 discussion site shows as “unknown site discussion” in Android app [duplicate]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/204574/area-51-discussion-site-shows-as-unknown-site-discussion-in-android-app) or [Add Area 51 Meta to the app](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/195419/add-area-51-meta-to-the-app) but yes I agree that its similar to these questions. Yes I could edit the existing questions but I have created this question to let developers track this issue differently and can manage easily.

**Current app version:** 0.1.81

### Steps to reproduce issues:

1. Open app, it shows Area51 site as an advertisement.
2. Click on advertisement, it will show 2-3 choice to open advertisement link with. If you select Chrome or browser, it opens successfully but choose SE android app.

### Issues:

1. site name is shown as "Unknown site a..." in title.
2. "No items to show..." text in center of the screen instead of Area51 site feed.

P.S. One reason I have already mentioned why I have created this question separately, another reason is I am not sure whether advertisement for area51 or other sites are also getting displayed.

Here are the snaps for the same issue/s.

[image]   [image][image]

Comment: @AsheeshR **I hope you have read this question fully**. Otherwise Thanks. And are you sure that this issue is duplicating with your? Because this issue is something regarding advertisement and displaying its feed in app.

Comment: The solution (and problems?) are the same for both cases. Hence, the vote.